# Get offset neighbors of an array

Tags: php, arrays, math, offset

### TL;DR

How can I slice an array to get a (user-defined) number of entries before and after a given offset (also user-defined) without go out of range. E.g:

```
$collection = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ];
```

If defined a limit of 2 and a starting offset of index 3 (D), the routine should return `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`: Two before `D` and just one after `D`, otherwise it would go out of range.

If defined a limit of 3 and a starting offset of index 0 (A), the routine should return `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, three after `A` and none before it, otherwise it would also go out of range.

> The slice must expand to always bring the number of elements defined by `$limit` before and after the entry found at `$offset`. Unless one of the sides goes out of range, of course

---

I'm trying to figure a simple, perhaps mathematical only way, to get the offset neighbors of an indexed (and currently sequential) array, but with a custom limit.

First thing that came to me was to use [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/array_slice):

```
$collection = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset     = 0; //rand( 0, 25 );
$limit      = 3;

$length = count( $collection );

if( $offset >= $length ) {
    throw new \OutOfRangeException( 'Requested offset exceeds the size of Collection' );
}

$start = ( $offset - $limit ) >= 0 ? ( $offset - $limit ) : 0;
$end   = $limit + 2;

$slice = array_slice( $collection, $start, $end );
```

From what I could test, `$start` is working fine. I'm forcing the first offset to avoid a negative one.

Then I first thought I could just increase `$limit` by **2** to have the "second offset", and of course it didn't work, but that was my very fault. I don't use that function so often >.<

Then I changed the logic of `$end` to:

```
$end = $offset + $limit + 1;
```

The offset I've found in the collection, plus the limit and one more to include the very entry stored in `$offset`. It worked fine until `$offset` was set to 4 (E) or more. After that, for the letter 'F' the slice was going up to G, H up to I and so on o.O

I tried to search for a solution but what I could find so far were involving loops and complex conditions. As far as I can tell I shouldn't need that, after all if it's sequential, I could apply "simple" math over it.

But mine didn't work so I may be wrong...

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can't understand any of it

Comment: I've edited the question with an even more summarized version of the question

Comment: In the first example you take D, then why not take A in the second example ?

Comment: @procras seems correct what you write. In first example the startposition is in the array, in the second it's omitted. Which is correct?

Comment: Do you mean before the revision in which I removed my attempt (upper half) or after it. Because I checked what I wrote 3 times in the short version several times and as far as I can tell it's correct

Comment: @Bruno this part `If defined a limit of 3 and a starting offset of index 0 (A), the routine should return B, C, D, three before A and none before A` if the offset is 0 (A) and add three (D) the end result should be ABCD, but you list BCD. And to be picky, you write "three **before** A, BCD". In the normal alphabet BC and D is **after** A ;-)

Comment: Oh gosh... Now I see, that's obviously a typo. Can't have two different things at same place >.<

Comment: But you don't fix it... ?

Comment: Like I said in the original post, before the revision, I noticed that after my first attempt failed, after all I don't use array_slice() so often. I also said I've found some solutions involving loops and that's one of the reasons I came here to ask, to avoid a loop in favor of a mathematical solution. Both approaches, mick's and Andreas' sorcery (:p) worked, but for this very limited scenario. [Where I'm really going to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45516555/753531) neither of worked because treat the problem really like simple indexed arrays or  a string

Comment: By the way, the "mathematical" solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516733/1636522.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get offset neighbors of an array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516555/get-offset-neighbors-of-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto (To my surprise, I received yet another downvote on my correct answer today -- so it brought my attention back to this page.)  I am now wondering: Are your project values _actually_ "A" through "Z"?  Or did you just use single letters as values to simplify your question?  If they are anything other than unique single characters, that detail will ruin Andreas' clever regex approach.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa0fa96ec10885e3eab7d28e2e8960615e148ecb  Would you mind clarifying your project data/requirements for my curiosity?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is your cleanest approach -- no conditional calculations required.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a12f6ffe211b7905259242dd3b8a9fc237a5d3a))

```
$collection = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset     = 1; //rand( 0, 25 );
$limit      = 3;
$indices=array_flip(range($offset-$limit,$offset+$limit));  // genereate offset range and flip values to keys
//var_export($indices);
/*array (
  -2 => 0,
  -1 => 1,
  0 => 2,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 6,
)*/
var_export(array_intersect_key($collection,$indices));  // retain values with listed keys
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 'B',
  2 => 'C',
  3 => 'D',
  4 => 'E',
)
```

---

I can confirm that `array_fill_keys()` works just as well in place of `array_fill()`.  Here is another demo:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0cb1f774540941e1c1265c982b04a92c12aeb5bf))

```
$collection = range('A', 'Z');
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    $offset = rand(0, 25);
    $limit = rand(1, 5);
    echo "Offset: $offset\nLimit: $limit\n";
    var_export(array_intersect_key($collection, array_fill_keys(range($offset-$limit, $offset+$limit), null)));
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Offset: 13
Limit: 3
array (
  10 => 'K',
  11 => 'L',
  12 => 'M',
  13 => 'N',
  14 => 'O',
  15 => 'P',
  16 => 'Q',
)
---
Offset: 0
Limit: 5
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 'B',
  2 => 'C',
  3 => 'D',
  4 => 'E',
  5 => 'F',
)
---
Offset: 12
Limit: 2
array (
  10 => 'K',
  11 => 'L',
  12 => 'M',
  13 => 'N',
  14 => 'O',
)
---
Offset: 25
Limit: 3
array (
  22 => 'W',
  23 => 'X',
  24 => 'Y',
  25 => 'Z',
)
---
Offset: 11
Limit: 5
array (
  6 => 'G',
  7 => 'H',
  8 => 'I',
  9 => 'J',
  10 => 'K',
  11 => 'L',
  12 => 'M',
  13 => 'N',
  14 => 'O',
  15 => 'P',
  16 => 'Q',
)
---
```

Comment: Running a few tests with random values for both `$offset` and `$limit` and all of them worked. One thing got my attention: Why no validations? Aren't they needed or you just skipped them for the snippet?

Comment: You can include your throw condition if you don't trust the user input.  What if someone uses `$offset=26` and `$limit=1`?  Do they get `Z`?  Or do you want it to break?  That is the only thing to consider with your conditional check.

Comment: I was rethinking here and I believe it won't be necessary. Thank you for your solution :)

Comment: @Bruno have a look at my update. I think it's even simpler.

Comment: @Andreas You know that regex is a slower technique and your solution is much harder to comprehend.  (clever anyhow)

Comment: Why would it be harder to comprehend? Slower? Not sure about that. Prove it

Comment: Looking at your example depending on the version it's either close call or mine is faster (7.0) https://3v4l.org/dW319/perf#output https://3v4l.org/R7eff/perf#output

Comment: I'm not going to benchmark our answers (you are welcome to if you have time, I don't).  I'm saying categorically regex is slow.  You can remove the first param of `implode` if it is empty.  We are both using a total of 3 function calls.  I will be surprised if my method is slower, but speed is going to be unnoticeable to the end user on such a small operation.  I'd say it is harder to comprehend because of the concatenation and variables in your pattern.

Comment: ...family time, can't stay to chat this out.

Comment: If you just say regex is always slower then you haven't done your homework. Yes many times it is slower, but many times it's faster than array functions. If you don't want to benchmark it then we just go by php 7 scores and say that my code is 16 times faster.

Comment: Did you just downvote my correct answer? Are we really going to have bad blood over this?  If so, that is unfortunate as we swim in the same waters.  I did interpret your comment to Bruno as a taunt.  You could have asked for his attention on your answer or on the question, but you posted under my answer.  I didn't open your link, but if you say it is faster, fine. Your method also requires an output variable containing a multidimensional array to the global scope, mine does not.  I'm not going to apologize for using array functions on an array task.  The OP got 2 great answers, but at a cost.

Comment: I downvoted because of two reasons 1. You have not done your homework. But I can accept that and I would have let it go if it wasn't for the other. 2. You have no explanation or comments to your answer. It's an essential part of an answer. You should know that. Enough with that. But my array is not multidimensional. Again homework....

Comment: @Andreas My answer explains in the comments of the code.

Comment: My mistake about the multi-dim array, I was thinking preg_match_all

Comment: @Andreas I am now cutting into my family time, but I did a little homework and here's what I found pertaining to speed:  https://3v4l.org/YTpCN/perf#output and https://3v4l.org/qiOZG/perf#output  On System Time, over php7 my method does better.  On User Time, yours just noses mine out.  On Memory, yours is better on PHP7.2 but I nose you out below that.  As I said before, you method is clever and I wouldn't have thought to go that path.  So I am upvoting it.

Comment: I didnt get a chance to test array_fill_keys with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Edit again.
This is probably as light as you can possibly make this function.
It compares the start and end values with max and min to make sure it doesn't overflow/underflow.
The to output it uses a substr().
But you can also loop it or explode it. See link for that code.
https://3v4l.org/sfCKY

```
$alpha  = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$offset = 1;
$limit  = 6;

$start = max(0, $offset-$limit); //if offset-limit is negative value max() makes it 0
$end = min(strlen($alpha)-1, $offset+$limit);  // if offset+limit is greater than str lenght min will make it str lenght.

Echo substr($alpha, $start, $end-$start+1);
```

---

---

Edit I think I found the best solution. Preg_match.

```
$collection = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset     = 1;
$limit      = 6;

$alpha = implode("", $collection);

Preg_match("/.{0," . $limit ."}" . chr(65 +$offset) . ".{0," . $limit ."}/", $alpha, $match);
Var_dump($match);
```

Sorry for not including an explanation.
I build a regex pattern looking like `.{0,6}B.{0,6}` but 6 and B is variable from the inputs.
This means:
`.{0,6}` - match anything between zero and six times.
`B` - match a "B", literally.
`.{0,6}` - match anything between zero and six times again.

In the regex pattern I use chr() to convert a number ($offset) to a capital letter.
In this case offset is 1 so that means the second letter in alphabet (A is 0).
The $limit is used to, well limit the regex search. {0, `<$limit>`} this means match as many as you can between 0 and $limit.

https://3v4l.org/BVdiF

No calculations or array functions at all. Just a regex.

---

Not sure if I got it correct this time.
But calculate the start and end values of array slice depending on if you overflow or underflow on the offset limit.

```
$collection = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ];
$offset     = 4;
$limit      = 2;

If($offset>count($collection) || $offset < 0 || $limit ==0) die("inputs out of bounds");


If($offset-$limit >=0){
     $start = $offset-$limit;
}else{
     $start =0;
}

If($offset+$limit>count($collection)){
    $end = count($collection)-$offset+$limit;
}else{
    $end = $offset + $limit;
}
If($start ==0) $end++;

$result = array_slice($collection, $start, $end-$start+1);
Var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/0l1J6

Edit found some issues.
If start is 0 I needed to add 1, not otherwise.
End limit of max was not working as it should, thanks for pointing that out.
If limit is 0 error message.

I think I got all variations working now.

Comment: Close. Among all my attempts I suppressed to keep the post short I came to something more or less like this. Note that your `$limit` is pretty much acting like what array_slice()'s normally expects: a max number of elements in the array while it should be the entry at chosen offset PLUS the number of elements defined by `$limit` before AND `after`. Unless it goes out of range, in that case it's OK to have less (or none)

Comment: I think I noticed my error just before reading your post. I forgot to add +1 in the $end. Is the correct answer for input 2/2 = ABCDE? if so, I think I got it now.

Comment: Yes, if `$offset` is `2`, it should bring the two other offset before it (`A` and `B`) and the two offsets before it (`C` and `D`)

Comment: It was working fine until I chose the `E` offset (4). It returned just the `C` instead of `C`, `D` and `E`

Comment: I guess that with such a short array there are too many chances of false-positives. For example, using a bigger array like the `range()` I've been using to test (the original post), your approach works fine for the number of elements before the one at specified offset but it's resulting in twice as many elements before it, look: https://3v4l.org/BgFaH

Comment: Yes off course. Slice is length not end. I need to end-start+1. See here https://3v4l.org/Pcfms

Comment: Assuming I've build a small random test with the latest approach of yours, still not quite right, look: https://3v4l.org/dBpFu. Let's pick a random result, let's say... 7.2.0 Alpha 2 which got small random numbers `0` for offset and `10` for limit. It resulted in nothing before the `A` (correct) and **eleven** after it (one more than it should). Or maybe the output for version 5.6.27: nothing was returned. :o

Comment: Let me split this up... I do appreciate your effort and even more your time. You went far away than I could. Thank you for trying ;)

Comment: @Bruno my latest answer is not that. Look at the top of answer. Above the line. The preg_match. https://3v4l.org/kqXrH

Comment: I see now, apologies. It's very clever, a bit slow, yes, but it solves the issue. However I'm not sure what you did there. o.O

Comment: @Bruno I'm sorry for not including a explanation. I have edited to include it. Hope it is enough to be somewhat clear.

Comment: Just for future reference, split up the resulting string with an str_split() ;)

Comment: For the record, I did not downvote this answer, in fact, I upvoted it.

Comment: @Bruno you really need it as an array that badly? You know you can loop a string, and you can output individual parts just like arrays with strings. Like this `$str = "HELLO"; echo $str[1]; // "E".` or loop it in a for loop `$str[$i]` and instead of count of array, you use strlen($str) as the end of for loop.

Comment: Yes, I do, because this is going to be a resource of a Collection class, which is pretty much an array storing different kind of Objects. Because it was really hard for me to explain the goal I simplified with an array of letters.