# Get offset neighbors of an array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, collections

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45514720/753531) I raised a question about how to get N-neighbors of an array having user-defined starting offset and limit for the search. E.g:

Considering a Collection of 5 stdClass Objects to simplify (see below):

- If defined a `limit` of **2** and a starting offset of **3**, the routine should return the Object at offset `3`, the two other Objects before it and only one after it, otherwise it would go out of range.
- If defined a `limit` of **3** and a starting offset of **0**, the routine should return the first Object and the three other Objects after it. Nothing else before the first because, obviously, otherwise it would go out of range as well.

Both solutions presented by [@mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) and [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5159168/andreas) solved the issue but I ended up voting for [@mickmackusa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) simply because it's faster and because I'm not that versed in the sorcery [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5159168/andreas) did there (sorry buddy :p)

Well, the question was hard to explain to me so I simplified it with simple arrays. And even though it was still kind of hard to understand, that's why I decided to split this in a different thread, so:

> How can I retrieve the same kind of information having an array filled with mixed content, **specifically Objects**

I tried to apply, without success, both of the most updated solutions with this (fake) data:

```
$std1 = new\stdClass;
$std1 -> name = 'Name #1';

$std2 = new\stdClass;
$std2 -> name = 'Name #2';

$std3 = new\stdClass;
$std3 -> name = 'Name #3';

$std4 = new\stdClass;
$std4 -> name = 'Name #4';

$std5 = new\stdClass;
$std5 -> name = 'Name #5';

$collection = [ $std1, $std2, $std3, $std4, $std5 ];
$offset     = rand( 0, 5 );
$limit      = rand( 1, 5 );

printf( 'Value at offset #%d: %s<br />', $offset, $collection[ $offset ] -> name );
printf( 'Random limit: %d<br />', $limit );

var_dump( $collection );
var_dump( getNeighborsMickVersion( $collection, $offset, $limit ) );
var_dump( getNeighborsAndreasVersion( $collection, $offset, $limit ) );

function getNeighborsMickVersion( array $collection, $offset = 0, $limit = 1 ) {

    return array_intersect_key(

        $collection,

        array_flip(
            range( ( $offset - $limit ), ( $offset + $limit ) )
        )
    );
}

function getNeighborsAndreasVersion( array $collection, $offset = 0, $limit = 1 ) {

    Preg_match("/.{0," . $limit ."}" . chr(65 +$offset) . ".{0," . $limit ."}/", implode("", $collection), $match);

    return str_split($match[0] );
}
```

Guess that worth to mention that in production these Object won't be simple stdClass, may not have a specific interface implemented nor anything like that.

Once again, I'm not copying others' solutions here to have a plug n' play code for my own. I'm kind of extending a different topic of mine to narrow a problem to a more specific scenario.

I did made an attempt which, in fact, solved half of the issue. The second part is what' giving me trouble.

Comment: And once again this marvelous community don't understand the question, down vote without expose the reason and worse vote to close. Stack Overflow used to be much better in past...

Comment: People must think you want the answer ready to use but they don't realize or, probably, didn't take the time to read both topics to understand you seem to not really how to proceed.

Comment: Precisely. Fine, I don't know how to solve but I this doesn't mean I want the solution ready to copy and paste in my code. If that was the case I would just explain the case without even try and, if you see in the other topic, I did try and solved half of the problem.

Comment: Updated to make things easier to understand (hopefully) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45532145/1636522.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto I'd like to help you here, but I don't know what you are having trouble with.  I keep re-reading your question.  I have run your code over and over, It seems my way keeps working as expected and Andreas' code never works.  Can you explain what your issue is so that I can post an answer that you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look : https://3v4l.org/5Gt7B.

```
$padding = 6;
$letters = range('A', 'Z');
$i = 25;
$slice = array_slice(
  $letters, 
  $i - min($i, $padding), 
  $padding + 1 + min($i, $padding)
);
```

Note that argument 3 of `array_slice` is not an index : [RTM :-P](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php) Argument 2 (index) : `$i - min($i, $padding)` = shift to the "left" of the ith item until you reach zero. Argument 3 (length) : `$padding + 1 + min($i, $padding)` = take at least `$padding + 1` items.

Another example with some drawings :

```
$i = 1;
$padding = 2;
$letters = range('a', 'z');
$start = $i - min($i, $padding); // = 0
$length = $padding + 1 + min($i, $padding); // = 4
$slice = array_slice($letters, $start, $length);
```

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   ...
[ a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | ... ]
  ^   ^
  |   $i
  $start = shift by $padding or as much as possible
```

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   ...
[ a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | ... ]
                 $length
         <-----> = $padding items
     <---------> + the item in the middle
 <-------------> + $padding items or as much as possible
```

JS version (unlike `array_slice`, the second argument of `slice` is an index) :

```js
padding = 2;
letters = new Array(27).join(" ").split("");
letters = letters.map((x, i) => (i + 10).toString(36));
indexes = ["-1", " 0", " 1", " 2", "13", "24", "25", "26"];
for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
  index = parseInt(indexes[i], 10);
  s = letters.slice(
    index - Math.min(index, padding), 
    padding + index + 1
  );
  console.log(
    indexes[i], 
    letters[index] || "/", 
    "[" + s.join(", ") + "]"
  );
}
```

Comment: For those who wonder what "RTM" means, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45532145/revisions).